# SQL Server: join three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I was able to join 2 SQL tables use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1, Table2 with (nolock)
WHERE Table1.field1 = Table2.field2
```

Then I tried to join 3 SQL tables like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 with (nolock)
WHERE Table1.field1 = Table2.field2, Table1.field2 = Table3.field3
```

But it didn't work. Did I miss anything here? Or how do I join 3 tables properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you mean by didn't work. I'll take a guess and tell you to replace the last comma with `AND`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the **proper** ANSI JOIN syntax, you won't have any of those issues:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Table1
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 ON Table1.field1 = Table2.field2
INNER JOIN
    Table3 ON Table1.field2 = Table3.field3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are joining table in old style and for multiple condition you have to use `and` instead of `,`

Try to use inner join

Like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
inner join Table2 on  Table1.field1 = Table2.field2
inner join Table3 on Table1.field2 = Table3.field3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join Table2 WITH (NOLOCK)
 on Table1.field1 = Table2.field2
inner join Table3 WITH (NOLOCK)
 on Table1.field2 = Table3.field3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AND instead of ',' in where condition .
Like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 with (nolock)
WHERE Table1.field1 = Table2.field2 AND 
      Table1.field2 = Table3.field3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one.

```
   Select * from table1
            left join table2 on (table1.tablefield1 = table2.tablefield2)
            left join table3 on (table2.tablefield2 = table3.tablefield3)
```